# Bind TextBox with ReactiveUI and maintain Currency Format

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, string-formatting, reactiveui

Is there a way to bind a `decimal` to a WPF TextBox and specify a `StringFormat` (in this case Currency)? I've tried doing this with a property in the View Model, but editing in the TextBox becomes a little quirky as it tries to apply the formatting after every keystroke:

```
public string Moneys
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0:C}", Model.Moneys);
    }

    set
    {
        if ( decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Currency, null, out decimal decimalValue) )
        {
            Model.Moneys = decimalValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried setting the `DataContext` and used Xaml data binding instead. Xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Moneys, StringFormat=C0}" />
```

Code behind:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.Model)
    .Subscribe(x =>
   {
       DataContext = x;
   });
```

However, after changing `DataContext` the `{Binding}` does not change as I'd expected to.

Is there a way to use `this.Bind` and specify the `StringFormat`? for me, that would be the ideal solution

**UPDATE**

In the case of setting the `DataContext`, I realised that I should just be assigning it to the `ViewModel` and when `ViewModel.Model` changes, the template reflects the changes as it should. Here's my updated xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Model.Moneys, StringFormat=C0}" />
```

However, I would still like to know if you can set the `StringFormat` in the code behind using `ReactiveUI`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an inline Binding Converter, do the bind in the code behind (your textbox will need a name):

```
this.Bind(
    ViewModel, 
    x => x.ViewModel.Model.Moneys, 
    x => x.nameOfTheTextbox,
    x => ConvertToText(x),
    x => ConvertToDec(x));
```

And the methods:

```
private string ConvertToText(decimal value)
{
    return string.Format("{0:C}", value);
}

private decimal ConvertToDec(string value)
{
    decimal result;
    if (!decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Currency, null, out result))       
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    return result
}
```